# HTTP to HTTPS with Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module, azure-cdn

Currently, TSL/SSL redirection works, but it renders an SSL certificate error. If I don't specify the domain name under the `url` attribute then it will redirect to the Azure origin site.

```xml
<action type="Redirect" url="domain name/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, We have configured the CDN for the same with ssl certificate configured in the key vault. We enabled the https redirection using the option "HTTPS only" in web app. When we try to access site with https then it works fine, but when we try to access with only http then it will redirect to azurewebsites.net URL. To overcome from this, we have placed the redirection rule from HTTP to HTTPS in web.config. but its not working. It will redirect back to azurewebites.net. If I place the URLas mentioned above, it redirects but SSL error.

Comment: Could you select the HTTPS protocol in your Azure CDN endpoint?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-new-endpoint#create-a-new-cdn-endpoint

Comment: HTTPS protocol is selected.

Comment: What's the specific SSL error? do you use a custom domain in azure CDN and app service?

Comment: it says invalid certificate after redirecting to https. we have a custom domain in CDN but not in app services.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I could not face this issue when I configure an app service(default URL `https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net`) with HTTPS only `on`, and enable custom domain on Azure CDN endpoint. You could check the SSL certificate got configured successfully on the custom domain. It will look like this with a CDN managed certificate:

[image]

If you use your own SSL certificate, you must create it with an [allowed certificate authority (CA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-troubleshoot-allowed-ca). You need to upload it on your Azure key vault which is in the same subscription as the Azure CDN profile. Then you need to [register Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate#register-azure-cdn) and [grant Azure CDN access to your key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate#grant-azure-cdn-access-to-your-key-vault). Then you could select the certificate for Azure CDN to deploy, and select `On` to enable HTTPS. You could follow these steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate#ssl-certificates).

Comment: we have followed all the above said steps. We are to able to access the site with https but issues occurs when we try to access http. The redirection doesn't work at all with CDN. The http site redirects to https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net not to the custom domain. When we try to implement a URL rewrite, it will direct but gives SSL error.

Comment: Do you use Azure CDN Standard from Microsoft profiles?  I am using Premium Verizon CDN provider. I have not used a URL rewrite, just enable `https only` on app service. Could you access the web app default URL via HTTP, it will redirect to https? And could you try to use the CDN managed certificate?

Comment: I know its been a quite long since i haven't commented on this issue, but the http to https redirection is still not working. I have done all the configuration  which is provided in the azure provided document. I'm using microsoft CDN for the web apps. Is there any other possibilities to fix the issue. If i remove the CDN, the redirection works fine. The issue occurs once i configure the CDN. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm using the RuleEngine available in the CDN (standard Microsoft pricing tier) to redirect http to https. It works as expected.